# How To Test Routes In Rails 3 Using RSpec2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

What am I missing here?

```
it "should recognize a specific api route" do
       assert_routing("/api/api_email/69399ead0ed4ded38e7a101f7c8faf.json", {:controller => "places", :action => "api_email", :api_id => "69399ead0ed4ded38e7a101f7c8faf"})
   end
```

The controller is correct, the action as well, and the :api_id as well. However, it returns false.